# Calculate $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^4}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Calculate, $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^4}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},$$ if there exist.

My attempt:

I have tried several paths, for instance: $x=0$, $y=0$, $y=x^m$. In all the cases I got that the limit is $0$. But I couldn't figure out how to prove it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $$0\leq  \dfrac{x^4}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq|x|.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, sir!

Comment: @Gerschgorin   You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $y<1$ and using polar coordinates we have

$$\dfrac{x^4}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \le \dfrac{x^4}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} =r \sin^4\theta \to 0$$